# Laravel raw query and including model relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to return a single post with a sub-query to include a count of down-votes and up-votes. I am able to achieve this by using a raw query.

However doing so means that I can no longer access the post models relations e.g. comments.

Is there more of an Eloquent way I can do this to keep the models relations?

Or is there a better way I could be going about the whole thing? Would love to hear how you would go about it.

```
$post = DB::select(
        "SELECT post.*, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_votes 
        WHERE type = 1 
        AND post_id = posts.id) 
        AS up_votes, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_votes 
        WHERE type = 2 
        AND post_id = posts.id) 
        AS down_votes 
        FROM posts 
        INNER JOIN posts_votes ON posts.id = posts_votes.post_id
        WHERE posts.id = ?", [$id])[0];
```

Comment: use `Posts::setect` with `->where(function($subquery) {})`

Comment: you can use raw with Eloquent model like post::raw("sql query")->with("relation")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Post::select('*')
->addSelect(DB::raw('
    (select count(*) 
    from posts_votes 
    where type = 1 
    and post_id = posts.id) 
    as up_votes
'))
->addSelect(DB::raw('
    (select count(*) 
    from posts_votes 
    where type = 2 
    and post_id = posts.id) 
    as down_votes
'))
->whereIn('id', $ids)
->get();
```

Comment: This worked well for me. As @DivyankMunjapara commented, I could have just added `->with('relation)` to the end of my query. However I find this method to be more Eloquent like. Only thing I had to change in my case was `whereIn()` to `where` as I am only querying one post.

Comment: Ive got one for you (maybe I should open another question?). Using the above example, how would I go about applying the `posts_votes` count to the `$posts->children()` ?

Comment: @patskot u could just add all the selects to the children. $posts->children()->select($all)
->addSelect($upvotesquery)
->addSelect($downvotequery)->get(). In this case I would create a scope on your Post model. scopeUpDownVotes() for example

Comment: Creating a reusable scope for the model worked wonders! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it's the first result I get when I google "laravel relation raw query", so it might be useful for other people that are searching the same thing.

I managed to solve it like this:

```
$query = ""; //raw query goes here
$result = Model::fromQuery($query);
$result->load('relationship');
```

Make sure your custom raw query contains the proper columns specified in the model, otherwise the relationship will always return null.

Tested on Laravel 6.17.0

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked great for me:

```
Model::where('condition_one', 1)->doesntHave('RelationShip')->get();
```